# Available operators in JSF 2.0 ValueExpression

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I have been using expressions like this in JSF 1.2: `rendered="#{foo.bar!=null && !foo.isBar}"`. However in JSF 2.0 I've found this doesn't work, and `rendered="#{foo.bar!=null and !foo.isBar}"` comes out to be the solution that doesn't throw any `Exception`.

Please tell me what operators can be used in these situations!

Thanks in advance, Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` needs escaping in XML, which is why `and` works and `&&` doesn't. You would have to write `&amp;&amp;`. In any case neither is correct. If `x` has a boolean property `bar`, the way to test it in EL is via `#{x.bar}`, not `#{x.isBar}`.

The EL operators are defined in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html).